# Язык меток: русский или английский (а также синонимы)

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Меткам на каком языке должно отдаваться предпочтение?

Кроме того, уже появляются проблемы с метками на двух языках:

- [хэшкод](/questions/tagged/%d1%85%d1%8d%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4) и [hashcode](/questions/tagged/hashcode)
- [модерация](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) и [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation)

Их следует сделать синонимами.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Это русскоязычный сайт, поэтому все метки должны быть на русском языке. Если обнаруживаются одинаковые теги на разных языках, они должны быть отмечены как синонимы, а русскоязычная версия отмечена как основная (если не является транслитом, и в прочих случаях, когда английский каноничен).

Открытый вопрос — что делать с обязательными метками и метками для модераторов: [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) и др. В идеале они тоже должны быть на русском языке, чтобы не смущать пользователей, но я не знаю, поддерживает ли движок их локализацию.

То есть в целом алгоритм следующий: если выбор есть, выбираем русский, в остальных случаях выбираем оригинальное название:

- для [1с](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/1%d1%81) и [кумир](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80) русские названия без вариантов;
- для [boost](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost) и [com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/com) английские названия без вариантов;
- для [regular-expressions](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regular-expressions) / [регулярные-выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) выбираем русское название.

Так как некоторое количество юзеров всё равно будет пытаться использовать локализованные названия, то можно добавлять синонимы: [буст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82), [си](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8) и др.

Comment: Хм. А что делать с entity-framework, COM, boost и всяким таким? Они, наверное, вовсе не переводятся.

Comment: @VladD Поэтому я и сказал: кроме случаев, когда английский каноничен. То есть, если выбор есть, выбираем русский, в остальных случаях выбираем оригинальное название. Как-то так. Скажем, для [tag:1С] или [tag:КуМир] русские названия без вариантов, для [tag:boost] или [tag:com] — английские, а в случае, если есть выбор, например, [tag:regular-expressions] / [tag:регулярные-выражения], то выбираем русское.

Comment: Теперь понял, согласен.

Comment: Влияют ли теги на релевантность результатов поиска в гугле и прочих?

Comment: @Anatol Да, но гугл часто справляется с синонимами.

Answer (score 6):

Метки должны быть максимально на русском, кроме случаев, когда метка обозначает собственное имя языка программирования (`c`, но не `си`), библиотеки и т.п.

В случаях, когда англоязычный синоним русскоязычной метки уже имеет больше вопросов - создание синонима к русскоязычному варианту невозможно. Вероятно, будет требоваться помощь администрации.

Comment: Создание синонимов стандартным маршрутом — это вообще долгое и неэффективное занятие. Мало того, что нужны обладатели репутации в тегах с нужной привилегией, так ещё нужно, чтобы они заглянули на страницу с синонимами, которая чертовски хорошо запрятана (удивлюсь, если хотя бы 1% юзеров знает, как до неё добраться через интерфейс). Так что администрации придётся попотеть.

Answer (score 4):

Считаю, что по крайней мере названия технологий и специализаций должны остаться на английском (русские варианты - синонимами).
Мы живем не на острове, а английский - это международный язык, особенно в IT. Большая часть ресурсов остается на английском и его в любом случае надо изучать. Оправданий нет.

Да, в меня сейчас полетят камни )

JUnit > ЯЕдиница
UX, usability > эргономика?
GUI > ГИП

Comment: Есть устоявшиеся понятия, их, разумеется, переводить не стоит. QA, кстати, в большинстве случаев используется как эвфемизм. Не хотят быть отделом тестирования и тестерами, хотят быть отделом контроля качества и специалистами по QA. Поэтому, я считаю, в `QA` нет смысла, когда есть `тестирование`

Comment: QA это более широкая область деятельности, чем тестирование.

Comment: @Nofate да, про тестирование я согласен.

Comment: @Nofate: последняя прочитанная мной книга говорит о том, что это даже не часть и целое, а просто различные области.

Comment: «калька» просочилась даже в википедию: [юзабилити](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8)