# Вопрос по языку меток на meta.ru.stackoverflow

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, локализация, метки, мета

Я заметил, что на мете стали плодиться метки на английском, хотя в какой-то момент возникал вопрос о переводе в том числе и стандартных меток ([faq](/questions/tagged/faq), [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)) на русский. Насколько я понял, с обязательными метками есть некоторые затруднения, связанные с движком сайта, но по остальным меткам наблюдается расхождение мнений, вплоть до создания меток на двух языках ([hachcode](/questions/tagged/hachcode), [хэшкод](/questions/tagged/%d1%85%d1%8d%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4); [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation), [модерация](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) и т.п.).

Предлагаю определиться с политикой относительно языка меток, чтобы не создавать хаос в том числе и на мете.

Так как сайт русскоязычный, вероятно, приоритетнее будет перевести английские метки на русский.

> Примечание редактора: для меток Меты используйте синтаксис `[meta-tag:tagname]`

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/36/10105

Comment: Добавлю пояснение о том, что указанный в комментарии выше вопрос не полный дубликат, так как относится к основному сайту

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если есть выбор, следует выбирать русскую версию. Процитирую свой [ответ в похожем вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/37):

> Это русскоязычный сайт, поэтому все метки должны быть на русском языке. Если обнаруживаются одинаковые теги на разных языках, они должны быть отмечены как синонимы, а русскоязычная версия отмечена как основная (если не является транслитом, и в прочих случаях, когда английский каноничен).