# Синонимы меток на Мете: [русский] < [english]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

[Вопрос по языку меток на meta.ru.stackoverflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292/181472)

Предлагаю синонимизировать англоязычные метки к переводам.

Цель - заранее задать порядок, который будет сохраняться в будущих вопросах на мете.

- [удаление-метки](/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8) << [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request)
- [синонимы-меток](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba) << [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms)
- [замена-меток](/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba) << [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging)
- [знаки](/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8) << [badges](/questions/tagged/badges)
- [чат](/questions/tagged/%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82) << [chat](/questions/tagged/chat)
- [уведомления](/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) << [notifications](/questions/tagged/notifications)
- [голосование](/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) << [votes](/questions/tagged/votes)
- [голоса-против](/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2) << [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes)
- [голоса-за](/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0) << [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes)
- [страница-профиля](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f) << [profile-page](/questions/tagged/profile-page)
- [кириллица](/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0) << [cyrillic](/questions/tagged/cyrillic)
- [дизайн](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd) << [design](/questions/tagged/design)

Некоторые англоязычные метки уже заменил, так что по ним ноль вопросов. Но они появятся снова, в том числе потому, что существуют на en.so.

Некоторых русскоязычных еще нет, но они нужны на замену англоязычным.

Comment: Подтвердил почти все синонимы меток, что были в системе Stack Overflow на русском. Буду просматривать несколько раз в месяц, подтверждая по мере поступления.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а что со служебными метками вроде bug? Их нельзя переименовать?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Николай, я только что проверил — ни одного синонима из этого списка нет. Какие условия должны выполняться, чтобы их утвердить?

Comment: По трагическому стечению обстоятельств, я не заметил "Мета" в заголовке вопроса. Поправил метки на Мете. Единственное, использовал [meta-tag:страница-учётной-записи] вместо [meta-tag:страница-профиля] согласно переводу.

Comment: На сколько я могу видеть, служебные метки переименовать можно. Завел задачу.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky мне кажется, лучше синоним, чем переименование. Это облегчит адаптацию участников en.so

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, что именно следует поправить? [Посмотрел, вроде бы они синонимами добавлены](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8/synonyms).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я имел в виду переименование служебных меток. А с этими всё в порядке.

Comment: Хорошо, так и будем поступать!