# есть ли [исключения] для [exception]?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

в русле стратегической программы по [русификации меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292/178576) предлагаю сделать метку [exception](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception) (109 вопросов) синонимом метки [исключения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) (36 вопросов).

---

кстати, там рядом обретается ещё [обработка-исключений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9) (8 вопросов).

вроде бы, сущность иная. но, может быть, стоит и её тоже сделать синонимом для той же метки [исключения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)?

---

связанная тема: [Язык меток: русский или английский (а также синонимы)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/36/178576)

Comment: По идее, обработка исключений, отдельная от самых исключений, очень редкое событие. Так что я за синонимизацию всех трёх.

Comment: Действительно, вряд ли потребуется настолько конкретно задавать область вопроса, чтобы обработка исключений помогла, а исключения не подходили бы.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

UPD:

- подтвердил синонимы
- произвел объединение (замену) меток.

---

Подерживаю [исключения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) в качестве основного варианта.

[обработка-исключений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9) — тоже синонимизировать.

[Предложил синонимы, можно голосовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/synonyms).

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, добавить [meta-tag:статус-завершено]?

Comment: @Vadim добавил статус

Answer (score 1):

На enSO вроде было решение, что это разные метки. Хотя, могу с чем-то другим путать.