# Нужны ли запретительные правила в отношении слов из английского языка?

Tags: обсуждение, стиль, русский-язык

Как русскоязычное сообщество SO относится к "словам" вроде: "лайк", "пост", "репост", "парсинг", "топик", "сабж", "шаринг" и т.п?

Есть ли какие-то запретительные правила в отношении оных и нужны ли они?

Comment: Сабж, конечно, интересный и я с удовольствием бы ради такого расшарил бы свою стену во вк,  лайкнул бы и репостнул, чтоб поделиться сим постом. Зацепил.

Answer (score 12):

При локализации сайта переводчики старались по возможности использовать не заимствованные, а более-менее русскоязычные термины:

- tag - метка
- review - проверка
- flag - тревога

Однако участники вольны использовать те термины, которые хотят. Я считаю, что проверять, запрещать и специально заменять заимствования - недопустимо и невозможно. Иначе мы превратимся в GrammarNazi Overflow и Censorship Exchange.

Подробнее:

- [Язык меток: русский или английский (а также синонимы)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/36/181472)
- [Вопрос по языку меток на meta.ru.stackoverflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292/181472)

Comment: @edem суть и цель сайта совсем не в том, чтобы следовать правилам. Наоборот, правила нужны для поддержки цели сайта -  накопления базы практических решений.