# Не пора ли экранировать [screen]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Метка [screen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen) расставлена абсолютно бессистемно. Вероятнее всего из-за неоднозначности термина *screen*. Ею помечены вопросы, относящиеся к (список не исчерпывающий):

- <s>программе *gnu/screen*</s> (создана метка [gnu-screen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-screen))
- вёрстке сайтов
- мониторам как физическим устройствам
- экранам как логическим устройствам
- заставкам
- снимкам экрана
- android
- unity3d

уже существующие и пересекающиеся по смыслу метки, которые стоит либо удалить, либо задействовать в соответствующих вопросах вместо [screen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen), добавив (где отсутствует) краткое описание (естественно, с руководством для использования метки):

- [display](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/display) — 39 вопросов
- [монитор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80) — 16 вопросов
- [screenshots](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshots) — 43 вопроса
- [скриншот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82) — 14 вопосов
- [скриншоты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b) — 2 вопроса
- [экран](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd) — 34 вопроса

ещё больше меток просто не хватает. Надо бы придумать для них подходящие названия и краткие описания (с руководством по использованию).

---

связанный вопрос: [один [скриншот] хорошо, а [скриншоты] лучше](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8147/178576)

Answer (score 2):

учитывая результаты вопроса [Язык меток: русский или английский (а также синонимы)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/36/178576), предлагаю [screen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen) (в данный момент — 46 вопросов) сделать синонимом для [экран](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd) (34 вопроса).

т.е., чтобы при попытке использвать метку [screen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen) она автоматически заменялась меткой [экран](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd).

естественно, это не отменяет необходимости проставить более подходящие метки для (части) вопросов, сейчас носящих метку [screen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen).

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю удалить эту метку. Ну действительно, зачем она нужна?

- К верстке сайтов она вообще никак не подходит.
- К мониторам, как к физическим устройствам, она тоже не подходит
- К экранам, как логическим устройствам, лучше подходит именно [экран](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd), а еще лучше более точные метки, вроде [межсетевой-экран](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd)
- К заставкам тоже не подходит
- К снимкам экрана?
- Прочие вещи, к которым она вообще ну никак...

Comment: создадут заново. лучше синонимизировать.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Можно добавить ее в черный список