# один [скриншот] хорошо, а [скриншоты] лучше

Tags: обсуждение, метки, синонимы-меток

имеются метки:

- [скриншот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82) — 14 вопросов
- [скриншоты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b) — 2 вопроса
- [screenshots](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshots) — 43 вопроса

надо бы как-то унифицировать (учитывая [Язык меток: русский или английский (а также синонимы)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/36/178576)).

---

наткнулся в процессе попыток навести порядок со [screen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen): [Не пора ли экранировать [screen]?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8146/178576)

Comment: Кстати, в русском языке нет слова "скриншот". Лучше использовать термин "снимок экрана".

Comment: @mymedia, такой метки нет, потому я её и не упомянул. изложите, пожалуйста, ваше предложение в виде ответа

Answer (score 11):

ну и для полноты совсем третий вариант:

1. оставить метку [скриншоты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b) как есть
2. метки [скриншот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82) и [screenshots](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshots) сделать синонимами метки [скриншоты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b)

Answer (score 7):

излагаю и дополняю предложение от @mymedia:

1. переименовать метку [screenshots](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshots) в [снимок-экрана](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)
2. сделать метки [скриншот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82) и [скриншоты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b) синонимами метки [снимок-экрана](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

---

по действующему соглашению в названиях меток пишутся на русском языке. с английского языка слово "screenshot" переводится как "снимок экрана".

примеры использования:

- в проекте gnome - https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-screenshot/blob/master/po/ru.po#L120
- в программах майкрософт - https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/language/Search

Comment: бррррррррр... сложно как-то

Comment: @Qwertiy, переименовать сложно? ну, пусть тоже будет синонимом.

Comment: нет, я имел в виду, что [tag:снимок-экрана] - это сложно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, предлагайте свой вариант

Comment: @Qwertiy Это вписывается в тенденцию борьбы за чистоту русского языка на сайте. Слово "скриншот" - варваризм, хоть оно и часто встречается в разговороной речи, в документации обычно употребляется "снимок экрана". В названии метки тоже предпочтительнее "правильный" вариант. У нас же "инспекция-кода", а не "код-ревью".

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, нет тут такой борьбы. А метку [tag:снимок-экрана] вообще даже никто не создал.

Answer (score -5):

ещё один вариант решения (перекликается с недовольством, выраженным @Qwertiy в комментариях к первому варианту):

1. метку [screenshots](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshots) оставить как есть
2. метки [скриншот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82) и [скриншоты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b) сделать синонимами метки [screenshots](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshots)