# Нужно синонимизировать метки [screen] и [экран]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Нужно синонимизировать метки (у обеих нет описания):

- [screen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen) (71 вопрос)
- [экран](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd) (62 вопроса)

Основная - [экран](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd), потому что она на русском.

Comment: Что интересно, вопросов, в которых есть обе метки всего одна штука.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8146/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-screen?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 78 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 71 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 70 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'screen': [screen] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 132
tag remapping of [экран] and [screen] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym screen -> экран was approved!
```