# Синонимизировать и объединить селекторы

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть две метки [селекторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b) и [selector](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selector), предлагаю их объединить. По русскоязычной метке вопросов явно больше, она во множественном числе, обе метки используется для CSS-селекторов, как и задумано.

Comment: Еще встречаются метки [tag:queryselector] и [tag:queryselectorall] 10 + 4 вопросов

Comment: @РустамГимранов Тоже предлагаете их синонимизировать сюда?

Comment: Да вообще удалить `queryselector` `queryselectorall`. По аналогии с [комментарием](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9322/?noredirect=1#comment38563_9324). А так, желательно, чтобы метка была [tag:css-selectors], чтобы она всплывала на первом выпадающем списке при наборе букв **css**.

Comment: @РустамГимранов К сожаленью вынужден не согласиться по поводу удаления данных меток, так как использований данных функций в JavaScript может не иметь никакого отношения к CSS-селекторам. К примеру, для данного вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/942362/220571. Их использование вызывает вопросы (то что `document.querySelector` возвращает один элемент, а не массив, то что `document.querySelectorAll` возвращает не массив, а `NodeList` и т.д.).

Comment: @Suvitruf, чего химичишь?

Comment: @Qwertiy в смысле?

Comment: @Suvitruf, [tag:важное] зачем?

Comment: @Qwertiy Чтобы внимание к вопросу привлечь, очевидно же.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, так вот я и не пони маю, чего его привлекать...

Comment: @Qwertiy Чтобы вопросы по синонимизации решались широкими народными массами, а не повисали в воздухе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю основной меткой сделать новую метку [css-селекторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b) (или на худой конец [css-selectors](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors)) и присоединить обсуждаемые метки туда, а для андроида выделить отдельную метку [android-selector](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-selector). Данная структура предотвратит неверные использования меток и их неоднозначности.

#### Почему это важно?

Почему это важно — можно увидеть на примере одноимённой метки [selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selector) на enSO. Использование метки редко совпадает с описанием, однозначности в использовании нет никакой, при этом чаще всего её используют в значении именно CSS-селекторов.

#### JavaScript/jQuery

Для JavaScript селекторы используются также как и в CSS, то есть имеется одно и то же. В jQuery есть очень небольшое подмножество селекторов, которых нет в CSS, но я не вижу практического смысла для отдельной метки, если мне не приведут обратный пример.

Comment: Присоединить = синонимизировать или поменять метку просто?

Comment: @Suvitruf Синонимизировать.

Comment: Про js, селекторов типо `document.querySelector("a")` там хватает, и это не связано с css никак.

Comment: @Suvitruf А чем это от CSS селекторов отличается? Один в один принцип по которому выбираются элементы.

Comment: Я могу использовать js селектор, ничего не зная о css. Я, всё же, эти штуки разграничиваю.

Comment: @Suvitruf Вы что-то путаете явно, вот к примеру цитирую [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector): "***selectors***
A DOMString containing one or more selectors to match. This string must be a valid CSS selector string;". Вы не сможете использовать эту функцию не использовав CSS-селектор.

Comment: Не уверен по поводу [tag:css-селекторы], там есть метки аля [tag:css-filters] (а не [tag:css-фильтры]). Я бы предложил, всё же, юзать [tag:css-selectors].

Comment: @Suvitruf Как по мне, русскоязычный вариант более предпочтителен. В любом случае, даже англоязычный вариант будет лучше, чем всё оставить как есть.

Comment: Пока синонимизировал к [tag:css-selectors]. Можно отдельным вопросом создать обсуждение по поводу en vs ru метки.

Comment: @Suvitruf Спасибо вам большое, прекрасная работа! По поводу ru vs en меток [было уже обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/36/220571) и там, как я вижу, сообщество выступило за максимальную русификацию, где это возможно.

Comment: Ага, помню. Просто я за одинаковый стиль. Но, с другой стороны, метки мы создаём, отталкиваясь от того, как пользователи используют. В данном случае, я не уверен как было бы лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала необходимо определиться с описанием метки и после решить, какие метки нужно объединить/удалить/не трогать. К тому же обсуждаемые метки не имеют описаний и это главным образом, и порождает споры и недопонимание.

---

[css-selector](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selector) - критерий выбора в древовидной структуре элементов, которые соответствуют HTML элементам в документе.

Используется в CSS  для привязки свойств стиля к элементам в документе.

Используется в JavaScript для выбора элементов, которые соответствуют CSS селектору или группе селекторов, разделенных запятой.

---

Помимо указанных мною в комментарии [queryselector](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queryselector)[queryselectorall](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queryselectorall), стоит уделить вниманию [[классы] [javascript]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B+javascript)

---

> К сожаленью вынужден не согласиться по поводу удаления данных меток ...
>   [*@VadimOvchinnikov*](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/220571)

Пусть будут, если это вызывает спор. Синонимизировать их (`qs`, `qsall`) к предложенным [селекторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b) [selector](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selector) точно нельзя. Уж лучше пройтись по вопросам и осмысленно (где это потребуется) добавить дополнительную метку [css-selector](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selector), например.

Тогда действительно не понятно: **как и задумано**. Сначала определения меток, а потом обсуждения.

Comment: Если суть вопроса в том, как формировать селектор (неважно для JS или CSS), то метка CSS-селекторы будет релевантна. Если вопрос про то что возвращают JS-функции `document.querySelector` или `document.querySelectorAll`, то это совсем другая история.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, так и я о том же: порядок нужно навести в данных метках. Цена вопроса менее 100 вопросов, извиняюсь. **Но**, предложите описание меткам в самом вопросе.

Comment: Я не силён в описаниях меток, описание CSS-селектора у меня будет крайне очевидным: CSS-селекторы определяют совокупность элементов. Также и про JS-функции.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, плохо. Вопрос тогда можно закрывать, так как его суть не понятна.

Comment: Ваше описание CSS-селекторов очень хорошее в вашем ответе, зачем вам моё? По вопросам по querySelector надо просто пройтись, вы тоже правильно заметили. Но метки querySelectorAll не обязательно удалять со всех вопросов. И действительно, на некоторые вопросы уместна будет метка CSS-селектор.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, я с вами полностью согласен. Но описание должно быть не просто хорошим, а точным. Почти час потратил, чтобы вкратце изложить описание, а получилась сплошная тафталогия. Нужно утвердить описание, но данному вопросу уже неделя, и в его обсуждении приняли участие только трое: печально.

Comment: @РустамГимранов в обсуждениях по меткам всегда мало участников )=

Comment: @Suvitruf, тогда предлагаю две метки оставить `с-кодом` и `без-кода` )

Comment: @РустамГимранов я завтра это ещё обмозгую в офисе.

Answer (score 0):

1. Есть ещё, к примеру, [Android селектор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selector+android).
2. > обе метки используется для CSS-селекторов, как и задумано

   Что значит "как и задумано"? Часть [этих](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b+jquery) вопросов, к слову, про js/jQuery, а не css вообще.

Comment: В JavaScript селекторы связаны c CSS, только в jQuery есть пара "своих", да и чаще всего нет смысла их как-то дифференцировать. Использование с меткой android вполне заслуживает отдельной метки (такая есть на enSO).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov если уж вы заговорили про SOen, то почему тогда не предложили использовать [css-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors)? =/

Comment: Кстати на enSO, с одноимённой меткой [selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selector) полная вакханалия, если посмотреть на использования и описание.

Comment: Если возможно, то в идеале сделать метку [tag:css-селекторы] или на худой конец [tag:css-selectors] и присоединить обсуждаемые метки туда, а для андроида выделить отдельную. Это удалит неоднозначность использования меток и сделает их более практичными, так как вопросов по CSS-селекторам будет на всегда на порядок больше и они не будут вперемешку с андроидом.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov нужно в ответах голосование устроить)

Comment: Я написал, но что-то не уверен по поводу активности голосования, поэтому тут лучше было бы волевое решение, как мне кажется. Можем подождать недельку-другую, авось будет обратная связь.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov хорошо бы все варианты в ответах запостить. Я метку [meta-tag:важное] повесил.

Comment: А все — это какие? И зачем? Если кому надо, то пусть постят другие.

Comment: Спасибо большое, кстати, за метку [tag:важное]. Впервые вижу такой шаг от модераторов SO:)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov странно, что раньше её не использовали. Обсуждение и решение вопросов по меткам довольно важная часть SOru.

Comment: Ну и да, вопросу тому 4 года. Стоит уже новый создать с ссылкой на старый и привести примеры комплексных меток как метка [tag:css-селекторы] из оного обсуждения. Может к какому-то другому решению придём. Я сейчас офф уже. Можете создать вопрос. Ну или я сам завтра создам (:

Comment: Если вам не сложно, то пожалуйста, создайте. Можно даже с меткой [tag:важное] для такого важного решения по разным меткам.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov [done](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9363/15479).