# Язык меток: русский или английский (особенно в случае составных меток)

Tags: обсуждение, метки

По следам недавнего обсуждения: [Синонимизировать и объединить селекторы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9322/15479).

Встал вопрос, как лучше назвать метку, [css-селекторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b) или [css-selectors](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors). По css есть похожие составные метки, к примеру, [css-filters](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-filters) (а не [css-фильтры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b)).

Было ещё обсуждение по яндекс-меткам: [Привести в порядок метки, ассоциированные с яндексом/yandex](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9260/15479).

А ещё ранее в бородатые годы, когда Сквидвард был жив, [мы решили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/36/15479), что предпочтения даём ru варианту написания меток.

Хотелось бы снова поднять этот вопрос и решить:

1. Выбираем централизованная подход к наименованию?
2. Под каждую метку своё обсуждение?
3. Что делать с составными метками в таком случае? Полностью на одном языке или допустимо совмещать? (e.g. [css-селекторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b), [яндекс-карты-jsapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b-jsapi), [яндекс-maps-jsapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-maps-jsapi))

Comment: Метки должны служить людям, а не наоборот. В общем случае, что более общеупотребительно, то и должно быть в имени метки.

Comment: Была история, заменили все метки на русский , так сказать [ответ уже есть :3](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36/%d0%af%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b?noredirect=1&lq=1) по крайней мере я думаю что этот вопрос аналогичен

Answer (score 10):

Не умирал так то Сквидвард. Написано же в профиле, сдуло. Но, если серьезно, я думаю, для составных меток можно применить те же принципы:

- Cлово "селекторы" по отношению к CSS обычно употребляется на русском. Даже если скормить поисковикам "css selectors" из браузера с включенным русским языком, большинство результатов будет содержать именно написание "CCS-селекторы". Не вижу проблем использовать смешанное имя.
- [яндекс-карты-jsapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b-jsapi), [яндекс-maps-jsapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-maps-jsapi) - этих меток пока никто не создавал, насколько я вижу. Если создадут, целесообразно синонимизировать к [яндекс-карты-jsapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b-jsapi), хотя бы потому что официальное название сервиса - [API Яндекс.Карт](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/). Английское написание yandex-maps употребляется в URL, но не в документации.

Словом, если есть выбор между полностью английским и частично русским вариантами, и при этом русский термин достаточно общеупотребителен в технических текстах, синонимизировать к частично русскому. Но если есть только метка с английским написанием, нет смысла переименовывать только ради унификации.

Comment: Ну вот на примере селекторов, как бы вы предложили сделать?

Comment: @Suvitruf Ну, синонимизировать все к [css-селекторы]. Хотя стоп, такую метку тоже еще не создали? Я уже запутался. Сейчас синонимы [селекторы] и [selector] -> [css-selectors], это точно правильно? Других селекторов не бывает?

Comment: Есть ещё [tag:android-selector].

Comment: "Жив" употреблено в переносном смысле, имеется ввиду профиль относительно данного сайта. Возможно, было бы корректно чтобы ТС записал в переносном смысле или заменил на "активен".

Comment: Кстати, [tag:andriod-selector] не имеет никакого отношения к CSS-селекторам, если что. Метки [tag:селекторы] и [tag:selector] выбраны как синонимы, потому что они так используются участниками. Можно, конечно, сделать как на enSO и оставить метку [selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selector?tab=Newest) как отдельную, но это глупо, так как её лепят на вопросы по CSS-селекторам на том же enSO.

Comment: @Suvitruf Если в [селекторы] действительно было большинство вопросов по CSS, то ОК, пусть будет так. Можно либо синонимизировать все к [css-селекторы], либо оставить пока как есть, раз метку еще никто не создал - особой необходимости нет.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Оставить как есть — плохая идея, 4 вопроса были к примеру по [tag:andoid-selector] изначально с меткой [tag:selector]. В итоге оставить всё как есть приведёт к ситуации как на enSO, когда метку лепят куда попало, но вопросов слишком много, чтобы всё за раз разгрести.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov как есть - это я имею в виду синонимы [селекторы], [selector] -> [css-selectors], без переименования в русскоязычный вариант.

Answer (score 5):

Исходя из того, что мы на сайте StackOverflow **на русском**, более того, вопросы на английском принято закрывать, логично, что приоритет должен отдаваться именно русскому языку.

В результате, правильным будет `css-селекторы` и пр., за исключением случаев, когда в русском нет соответствующего общепринятого термина.

Названия языков, систем, фреймворков и пр. писать на английском. Т.к. названия не переводят, английский для них более привычен, в т.ч. в документации.

На тему: Что "вопрошающие" чаще пишут.

Значительное число вопросов поступают от "новых пользователей", которые с разметкой далеко не всегда способны разобраться. Что говорить про "системный подход к меткам". Если мы хотим их систематизировать, то этим мы будем заниматься, а большинство "вопрошающих" сделает не правильно, что бы мы не решили.

Вопрос в том, кому и зачем нужны метки? Тем, кто задал свой первый и последний вопрос - не нужны.

Лично мне, как отвечающему, нужны для фильтрации. Мне не важно на каком они языке, лишь бы фильтр правильно работал.

Возможно, они нужны для индексации в поиске. Тогда, для решения вопроса выбора языка, надо исходить не из наших пожеланий, а из статистики поисковых запросов.

Answer (score 2):

Не вижу проблем со смешением языков в метке. Так что [css-селекторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b), [css-фильтры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b) и т.д.

Comment: А что такое "b n/ l/"?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov пьяный код по клавиатуре прошёл и закончил фразу, не переключив раскладку :)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, забыл раскладку переключить. Точнее, наоборот, переключил где не надо)

Answer (score -4):

Считаю для выбора наименований меток стоит также применять подход, основанном на подходящем переводе для "непонятных" явлений, таких как "css-селектор".

На деле "селектор" есть просто-напросто английское слово "selector" написанное русскими буквами, которое для русскоязычных людей не имеет ровным счётом никакого смысла, а вот для англоязычных людей очень даже имеет осмысленное значение: "select" — выбирать, "-or" — показать существительного образованного от глагола, в данном случае: выборщик, выбиратель и т.п.

Таким образом, "css-селектор" есть нечто иное, как "css-выборщик".

Другой пример.

"Валидация" — от англ. validation, что есть некое действие по проверке на соответствие чего-либо каким-либо правилам. Т.е. сверить. Сверка. Сверщик и т.п.

Да, не для всех слов можно сходу придумывать осмысленные названия, но без этого мы просто-напросто усложняем себе жизнь с каждым витком появления новых слов из-за океана, которые для нас не значат ровным счётом ничего, в отличие от людей, в языковой среде которых они были "рождены".

Comment: Но ведь термин "селекция" далеко не нов.

Answer (score -6):

Считаю, что комплексных меток лучше не делать. Ведь можно просто сделать две метки из разных категорий: "яндекс.карты" + "api" + "javascript". Как-то так.

Кстати, css-селекторы звучит тоже не очень. Лучше просто "css", и так ясно что про селекторы, в основном.

Насчет названий лучше либо решение свыше, либо обсуждение по каждой метке. Потому что для каждой метки свой предпочтительный язык. Лучше просто "css", чем "селекторы" в любых сочетаниях, и не дай бог "цсс". И лучше "яндекс.карты", чем "yandex.maps", потому что в ходу именно первый вариант. А с Гугл картами не всё так просто, нужно голосование, так навскидку сложно сказать, какой язык лучше подойдет.

Comment: api - это мета метка, которая, в целом, ни о чём не говорит. Такие метки, в целом, вообще не рекомендуется использовать.

Comment: @Suvitruf мета-метки надо использовать на Мете.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ (¬‿¬ )