# Не многовато ли у нас [микросервисов]?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Имеются две идентичные метки:

- [микросервисы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b) — 38 вопросов
- [microservices](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microservices) — 83 вопроса

Надо бы как-то синонимизировать/объединить (учитывая [Язык меток: русский или английский (а также синонимы)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/36/178576)).

Comment: Ждём результатов выборов, авось новые модераторы сделают.

Comment: Но-но-но, настоящие модераторы все еще на страже и при исполнении )

Comment: Как раз в тему [интернет выдал](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z7q0.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Синонимизировано в сторону [microservices](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microservices) » [микросервисы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b)

Comment: Похоже что выборы можно отменять.