# Объединить метки [pattern-matching] и [сопоставление-с-образцом]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть такие метки:

- [pattern-matching](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pattern-matching) - 22 вопроса
- [сопоставление-с-образцом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%86%d0%be%d0%bc) - 3 вопроса

Надо их объединить/синонимизировать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Синонимизировал и объединил в сторону русскоязычной [сопоставление-с-образцом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%86%d0%be%d0%bc).

Пока наблюдается эффект от кэширования и отображает только 3 вопроса (как был до объединения). <s>Скоро должно выравняться.</s> Уже нормально.

Comment: А почему в сторону русской?

Comment: @Danis потому что автор ответа переводчик и всё локализует на русский? :D

Comment: @Danis потому что "Stack Overflow **на русском**". Если есть предложение сделать наоборот, давайте оформим и обсудим. Поменять можно в обратную сторону легко при необходимости.

Comment: @Danis ну и вот была [темка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/36/176217).