# Зачем нам два [видео]?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

На основном сайте имеются две идентичные метки:

- [видео](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be) — 216 вопросов
- [video](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video) — 460 вопроса

Надо бы их как-то синонимизировать/объединить.
*(учитывая [Язык меток: русский или английский (а также синонимы)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/36/178576))*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Синонимизировал, объединил

[video](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video) → [видео](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be)