# Надо синонимизировать метки [migration] и [миграция]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю синонимизировать метки

- [migration](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migration) (134 вопроса) - есть описание
- [миграция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) (41 вопрос) - описания нет

Основная - [миграция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) (она на русском, см. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/37/507426). Описание нужно перенести из [migration](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migration).

Comment: В какую сторону? И стоило бы упомянуть, что у английской метки есть описание, а у русской - нет.

Comment: @Зонтик, думаю, что основная - [tag:миграция] (см. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/37/507426).

Comment: Но описание нужно перенести из английской метки!

Comment: Вы всегда можете править свои посты: для этого достаточно воспользоваться 
ссылкой [edit] под текстом вашего поста. Важную информацию лучше включать
непосредственно в исходное сообщение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 144 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 135 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 128 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'migration': [migration] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 169
tag remapping of [миграция] and [migration] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
4 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
13 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym migration -> миграция was approved!
```