# Надо синонимизировать метки на тему [ядро]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть две метки:

- [kernel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernel) (168 вопросов)
- [ядро](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be) (38 вопросов)

Надо бы их синонимизировать. В пользу какой я точно не знаю:

- kernel -- есть описание, больше вопросов.
- ядро -- на русском языке.

Как синонимизировать лучше поймут те, кто будут синонимизировать, то есть модераторы.

Comment: Конечно же [tag:ядро] - основная (см. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/37/507426).

Comment: Синонимизировано в сторону [tag:ядро]. Как извлечь описание из старой метки, выяснил [тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392759/339911). На текущий момент имеется еще [бага с количеством синонимов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389346/339911).

Comment: Интересно, у меня тот же баг.

Comment: @Зонтик так это баг сайта, он на всех один

Answer (score 2):

> Как синонимизировать лучше поймут те кто будут синонимизировать, то есть модераторы.

Процесс синонимизации должен выглядеть так: сообщество решает здесь, на мете, а модераторы только исполняют решение<sup>1</sup>.

Главной меткой в данном случае нужно сделать метку [ядро](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be).
В большинстве вопросов с меткой [kernel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernel) используется термин "ядро", а не "kernel". Значит, отдаём предпочтение русскоязычной метке. А описание можно скопировать из описания метки [kernel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernel) (только заменить в описании термин "kernel" на "ядро").

---

<sup>1</sup>Естественно, модераторы тоже могут участвовать в обсуждении. Я имею в виду то, что модератор не должен такие вещи решать в одиночку.